# Who taught Rabbi Yehudah that Nachshon Ben Aminadav “descended into the sea first” Sotah 37 a:3-6?

Tags: shemot-exodus, yam-suf, exodus, sotah

From what source did Rabbi Yehudah
learn that Nachshon Ben Aminadav “descended into the sea first” [Sotah 37 a:3-6](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.37a.3?lang=bi) since no details exist in [Shemot 14:22] about specific sons of Yisrael crossing Yam Suf?

Comment: It looks like Rabbi Yehuda gathered from various verses that Yehuda was the first tribe to jump in, and Nachshon was their Nasi, so likely he was first, being at the head of the tribe.

Comment: @Harel13 - So the dispute with R. Meir in [Sotah 37 a] is based on presumption not textual evidence?

Comment: I believe [this](https://moderntoraleadership.wordpress.com/2018/01/25/how-did-the-midrash-know-that-nachshon-jumped-into-the-sea-first/) will answer your question :)

Comment: Some textual evidence and some reasonable conclusion based on textual evidence. That, or a tradition that was first put down in writing in the name of Rabbi Yehuda. But this seems less likely because of his analysis of verses there in the gemara.